# Keep Websocket alive between activities in Android

Tags: java, kotlin, websocket, client, ktor

I am actually designing a Websocket app Client with Ktor in Android.

I have the server deployed in Heroku and it works as this simply way: the client requests what it needs and the server answers with the info. Then if the user is in the FirstActivity it will request what shops are (for show them in a RecyclerView). Or if the user is in the ChatActivity the client will request if there are new messages.

I read that I can create a class WebSocketClient which I can access from the whole app (this seems to be the better way and the one that I like). In the other hand, I can simply create a service and migrate WebSockets there.